# Finding the intersect point between between a parabola and a straight line

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$x^2 −2x = \frac{1}{2}x+1$

So I have a graph with having both of these equations and put the equations as one. I realize I have to turn this into $x^2-2.5x-1=0$ and then I have to factorize it but how does something times into $1$ and adds into $-2.5$

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 1):

There is a quadratic formula that lets you use the coefficients in a 2nd degree polynomial to find the variable. Let ax^2+bx+c=0

x= -b + or - root of b^2 - 4 a c 
divided by 2a.

Excuse the form, I'm not very familiar with formatting on this website.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the quadratic formula:

$$\frac{2.5\pm\sqrt{10.25}}{2}.$$

Comment: Please use LaTeX to typeset formulas so that they are easier to read. I did it now. Take a look at this guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/166535